# Getting error in console Uncaught ReferenceError: fnSubmit is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using many credential of same type. When I am clicking on submit button with particular credential I am getting error on browser console Uncaught ReferenceError: fnSubmit is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick but from all other credentials submit button is working successfully.
In browser element's js function is not displaying for particular user from which I am unable to submit the form and else all user js function is displaying.
Why am i getting this error for only one user. Please help. This is the production issue.

Thanks,
Pritam Sinha

Comment: Sounds like `fnSubmit` isn't global, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045 - but even better, avoid inline handlers entirely and use `addEventListener` instead

Comment: Suppose if it is not global then it should not work for any user. I have created many users and it is  working for all except one only.

Comment: Need a [MCVE] in order to debug